# How to start activerecords in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I started an app with the -O option, thus activerecords was not initiated.

I modified my app to contain require "active_record/railtie" in the application.rb file. nevertheless this does not provides the activerecord methods to the new models I created.

Any help is appreciated in advanced.

Comment: curious - what's the reason you don't want to initiate ActiveRecords? do you have an override?

Comment: yes im using dynamoid the [dynamoid gem](https://github.com/Veraticus/Dynamoid) to interact with aws dynamo db.  I already got it to work, nevertheless my new objects do not inherit methods such as "order" and "batch".

Comment: Are you sure that including activerecord will cause Dynamoid to be able to order and batch?

Comment: The dynamoid gem states examples in which the model inherits the aws-sdk and the dynamodb methods. But when p Mymodel.methods they are not listed. I started an app from scratch without the -O option and I still get no results.

Comment: These are the methods i currently obtain using different approaches: [link](http://pastebin.com/pwcsNeSp)